# Trigger click event not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is like this

```
  $Lynliste_Item = $(".grid03 li .head-text strong[data-id='2324']");
            if ($Lynliste_Item.length > 0) {
            alert($Lynliste_Item);
                $Lynliste_Item.trigger("click");
            }
```

When I executes this I am getting `[object Object]` in alert .but the click event never happens.Can any one point out what is going wrong here?Or tell me how I can debugg this issue?

Comment: is the click handler registered before the event is fired

Comment: Is it as simple as missing the semi-colon after the `alert()` statement?  To debug this, you can step through the code in a browser debugger (such as FireBug or Chrome tools) and see if the line of code is indeed being reached, as well as the runtime values of relevant variables.

Comment: @David thanks for notifying me on semi-colon.But it was not the problem.I am going to try with debugging as you told :)

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think you got the right point .Can you add it as answer if it works I can mark it as right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Based on the comments in the question</sub>

I think it is a simple problem of adding the handlers after the event is triggere

You need to add the click handlers before the event is triggered

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this correct syntax?

```
var Lynliste_Item = $(".grid03 li .head-text strong[data-id='2324']");
if (Lynliste_Item.length > 0) {
     alert(Lynliste_Item);
     $(Lynliste_Item).trigger("click");
     }
```

Comment: No, you don't need to pass a jQuery object to the jQuery function. It's not a dom element.